# Why do all components with Component selectors have to be used in an Angular 2 application?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

*Please be aware I am working with tutorial code here, so not everything is strictly correct, but it works. Most of the time.*

I have a component class that is decorated as follows:

```
@Component({
    selector: "click-here",
    template: `
        <button (click) = "onClickThere($event)">Click here!</button>
        {{clickMessage}}
    `
})
```

And it was used like this:

```
<body>
    <click-here>Loading...</click-here>
</body>
```

Then I added a new component class, but its decorator has:

`selector: "type-here"`

When I run the application with `npm start`, I get a legion of errors in the browser, starting with:

`The selector "click-here" did not match any elements`

Why does every selector have to match an element? Working like this is not feasible; there must be a way to be able to have multiple `Component` decorators, all with different `selector` values, and only use some of them. How would I achieve that? What am I doing wrong that the tutorial hasn't included a correct version of? Must each `Component` have a name or something?

Comment: Of course you can ([check it](http://plnkr.co/edit/guf5nhtOv5L6xlsIpHHl?p=preview)). You need to post your entire setup the tell for sure, but sounds like you *are* using them somehow.

Comment: So what if I'm using them? Is there a rule that says I can only use them once?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is only relevant to the element you instantiate with `bootstrap(MyComponent)`.

If you bootstrap a component and it doesn't match a selector, Angular doesn't know where it should place it.
Angular uses the selector to find the place where to insert the component into the DOM.

This also means you can currently bootstrap one component only once inside your page. There are plans to support overriding the selector when a component is passed to `bootstrap()` but currently this isn't supported.

See also https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/7136

For components used inside `MyComponent` this doesn't matter. You can have as many components as you want and only use what you need.

Comment: So the complaints from Angular are about components that are not bootstrapped?

Comment: No, the other way. The complaint is about the component that is bootstrapped but doesn't match a selector. Bootstrapped components need to match a selector.

Answer (score 0):

Components is related always to a html tag, it's like another html. a Component included a class, but there are class that can be not a component.

Component is like another html tag you know, by example, span, div, but a new one that you create and you can define what it's inside.

Components can be organised like a tree. accord last tutorial, before use a component you must to have always a main component (main.ts) ,  a module component ( app.module.ts)  and app component ( app.component.ts) , same for index.html , you can see more on the tutorial; so it's better you copy all the files, and you play or test your component in app.component.ts if you want to test just a component; but it's better you have children components, most of time app.component is associated with my-app tag:

```
<body>
 <my-app>Loading...</my-app>
</body>
```

tutorial link:
https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt1.html

Comment: Yes, I full well understand the concept of a component being like another HTML tag, in a way, but that has nothing to do with my question. If you read my question properly, you will see that I am basically asking why I can't have more than one component in my application and only use one in the HTML, i.e. the `index,.html` file.

Comment: i've replied component organisation is a 'tree', you do a dumm component and then you can have all the componentes you like like childrens.. you need always a root